# Viewing a Gem's Source Code

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ruby dabbler/newbie here who's not familiar with the ecosystem, so apologies if this is one of those super duh questions.

Is there a way to view **all** the files and/or source code installed by a gem?  That is, I just ran

```
$ gem install sass
```

And the sass gem is now a part of my local system

```
$ gem list --local
...
sass (3.1.16, 3.1.2)
...
```

I want to know what the `gem install` command put on my system.  Is there a command I can run to see **all** the files installed by the gem?

After some googling, `man gem` and `gem help commands`, I discovered the `contents` command.

$ gem contents sass

**However**, when I run this command with the aforementioned sass gem, I get the following results

```
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/engine_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/functions_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/extend_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/logger_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/css2sass_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/conversion_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/script_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/util/subset_map_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/util/multibyte_string_scanner_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/callbacks_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/importer_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/scss/css_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/scss/scss_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/scss/rx_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/util_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/script_conversion_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/less_conversion_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/cache_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/test/sass/plugin_test.rb
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/bin/sass
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/bin/sass-convert
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.16/bin/scss
```

However, this list seems incomplete as I know there are files in

```
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.2/lib/
```

Why does `contents` not show the files from `lib`?

Is it possible for a `gem` installer to install files outside of the gems folder?

Is there a command that can show **everything** installed by a gem?

Comment: This is the output I get with `gem contents sass`: https://gist.github.com/2598534 - all present and correct.

Comment: @matt Do you know know what gem contents reads from and/or what might be causing it to fail on my machine?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know what’s causing this. Perhaps you could try removing and reinstalling the gem.

Comment: Even more of a newbie: any way to view source of gem files ("online") *without* installing? -- E.g. some online service that would allow you to do an online "pastebin / fake" install?

Answer (score 64):

gem has an unpack command: http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-unpack

```
gem unpack rake
ls rake-0.4.3/
```

Answer (score 39):

There are two really good ways to do this. There is another gem which allows you to open the gem and edit. This gem is call [gem-open](https://github.com/fnando/gem-open)

```
gem install gem-open
```

then

```
gem open sass
```

Another way is to generate your own rdocs.

```
gem rdoc sass
```

You can then look at your rdocs by

```
gem server
```

Also if you are using rvm, you can type `rvm info` and it will show `GEM_HOME` location.
This will be where all your gems source code is.

```
cd $GEM_HOME
cd gems/sass-3.1.2/
```

Update:

This is the way I mostly do this now, when using bundler.

```
cd $(bundle show sass)
```

This will be the version of sass in your Gemfile.

Comment: Building on this answer, on Windows, if your [RubyGems version support it](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-open) you could open the folder in Explorer by using `gem open sass -e start`

Answer (score 17):

I usually open a gem by running this command from the console

```
EDITOR=<your editor> bundle open <name of gem>
```

Answer (score 7):

The lib/ directory you mentioned is for version 3.1.2 of the gem; `gem contents` without `--version` will just list one version (*it appears to pick the newest version, but I'm unable to verify this is always true*). What output do you get for `gem contents --version 3.1.2 sass`?

Comment: Ah, +1 thanks for that, I didn't realize there were two versions there (like I said, newbie)  However, both gem contents sass --version 3.1.16  and gem contents sass --version 3.1.2  fail to list the contents of their respective lib folders, and it (appears) that the lib folder is what makes them work

Comment: I just installed both those versions of sass and I can definitely see the lib/ folders listed for each one. Hopefully reinstalling the gem, as matt said, will help.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use just rename the .gem file to .tar and extract as a posix archive. The source code is inside it in the `lib` folder. See https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/how-extract-ruby-source-code-gem-packages-java for more details.

Comment: This is super helpful, for doing it in environments where ruby may not be set up, etc.  Thanks!  I thought it was probably something like that, just wasn't sure the exact format ...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `gem contents`, another command you might find useful is `gem environment`.  If you have multiple paths for your gem installations, they will all be listed under the "GEM PATHS" label.