# If I put my ruby code into a gem, is its source code secure?

Tags: ruby, security, compilation, rubygems

Its my understanding that when I make a gem I'm compiling my ruby code into some form of executable, right? Does this mean that unless someone used introspection techniques (which is an acceptable risk to me), my source code is secure?

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453249/viewing-a-gems-source-code) on unpacking a gem's source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to compile Ruby code into an executable or shared library using [Ruby's C API](http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/), that has nothing to do with gems.

A gem is just a collection of Ruby code (which could be regular scripts or compiled libraries) in a nice package for use with the rubygems package manager. It makes no effort to hide/protect the code.

Comment: So how exactly might I compile my ruby into C? Is there a tutorial somewhere I could use?

Comment: The link in my question is a comprehensive tutorial on the topic, assuming that you're comfortable with writing C code and delving through the Ruby source a bit. However, if you're considering C as a method of obfuscation, you will probably want to translate as much of your Ruby code into low-level API calls - which would be nontrivial. I have no idea how successful at obfuscation that would even be.

Answer (score 4):

A gem is not a compiled executable. It's not compiled at all. Ruby is interpreted. Creating a gem just bundles the necessary files together, much like a zip file or tar archive.

If you want your gem secure you should keep it out of rubygems.org. You can set up your own private gem server or you can just include your gem in projects that need it.

Comment: Some gems _are_ compiled. But usually the source code is included and they are compiled on the spot using the `mkmf` lib.

Comment: bitbucket is a nice, cheap, safe place as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
gem unpack
```

can extract your code. Never tried to do it and see if it's "human-readable" but you can try it before publishing your gem ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Its my understanding that when I make a gem I'm compiling my ruby code into some form of executable, right?

No. It's just a zipfile with some metadata. The contents of the zipfile are exactly what you put into them.

> Does this mean that unless someone used introspection techniques (which is an acceptable risk to me), my source code is secure?

This depends on what you mean by "secure", but is completely orthogonal to RubyGems.

If you mean that "it can't be stolen", then that is already guaranteed for you by copyright law. Unless you live in a really weird country, software is protected by copyright automatically from the moment you write it.

If you mean "cannot be reverse engineered", then that is impossible. If you want people to be able to run your program, then you must give it to them in a format that can be understood by the CPU. Humans are much smarter than computers, so, if the program can be understood by the CPU, then it can also be understood by a human.

There are two common ways around this, which I will call the "Nintendo way" and the "Google way".

The Nintendo way is to give the user the CPU as well as the program, therefore, the user's CPU doesn't have to understand it. However, that model is still flawed. As long as you give the user *something*, he can figure it out. In the end, it's all just maths and physics, which can be understood. And users are pretty clever. Note that, for example, most game consoles were *not* cracked by evil crime syndicates trying to steal the code or pirating games, no, they were cracked by students wanting to run Linux or BSD on their hardware.

The Google way is to give the user *nothing*. You type something in the search box, Google sends you back the results, but at no time does the software leave Google's datacenter.

Comment: times I've looked up the definition of orthogonal and forgotten it: 15+

Comment: orthogonal: "statistically independent"

Comment: It seems like using web services is a way to protect your software. The trick is to create a black box where you put your best code and protect that black box (i.e. web server). This means relying on web servers to do the main processing which is what I'm doing at this point.